# Input text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the person opening my webpage to enter his name so the the code below works.

```
var myName = "Parth Krishna";
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];
drawName(myName, letterColors);
bubbleShape = 'circle';
bounceBubbles();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code below is the html page.

So what will be the code if i want the user to enter his name and it can be stored in var myName?

Comment: Code is incomplete....

Comment: It is complete and it works just fine.

Comment: here is the link::   http://curlybraces.site88.net/site/index.html

Comment: `drawName` is not defined.. `bounceBubbles` is not defined as well.. What  made you think that this code will work ?

Comment: Don't post a link, post your functioning code and then ask a _specific_ question regarding an issue you are having with that code.

Comment: This is not a good question. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It looks like you haven't put in any effort at all. Your problem can be solved with a simple google search.

Comment: @RayNicholus sorry, my bad. i will search thoroughly first then ask the specific problem i am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Window prompt() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

```js
myName = prompt("Please enter your name");
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];
drawName(myName, letterColors);
if(myName.length>10)
  {
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
  }
else
  {
    bubbleShape = 'square';
  }
bounceBubbles();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope it isn't working:: Here is the link to my site where i am using it::
http://curlybraces.site88.net/site/index.html

Comment: Stop posting links to your site please.

Comment: console.log added to demonstrate the variable is being populated as the original question requests

Comment: @Xufox did you see the webpage i posted a link to??
i want the code to ask the name and then display in the format i have done.

just see the site first please.

Comment: @parth305 - StackOverflow is generally used to help answer specific questions for you, not do the full integration work.

Comment: @AnthonyAstige yea i came to know that later. So sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @parth305 No worries. I see you're adding more code to the question, which can be helpful to an extent.  If there is a lot of code to play with putting it in a [snippit](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) can help others get working solutions to you easily (they can quickly copy it into an answer, and tweak it to work).

Comment: @AnthonyAstige whoa i didn't know about that. Thanks i will use it

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Anthony Astige said, use `prompt`. Here is a full code example:

```
var myName = prompt('Please enter your name');
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];
drawName(myName, letterColors);
bubbleShape = 'circle';
bounceBubbles();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
myName = prompt("Please enter your name");
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];
drawName(myName, letterColors);
if(myName.length>10)
  {
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
  }
else
  {
    bubbleShape = 'square';
  }
bounceBubbles();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the final answer which i wanted.